# In GameCenter realtime multiplayer how to identify who is host?

Tags: unity, ios, game-center

In GameCenter real-time multiplayer how to identify who is a host?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't have experience with GameCenter, but a quick online search gave a handful of results that might be relevant. Did you try any of these?

Comment: In Game Center Real-time multiplayer I have maximum 2 Player so my question is how to identify which player have 1st Turn to select Level?

Comment: Have you tried searching online? If you did, and a tutorial you followed didn't work, it would help to mention which one it was and why it failed. Otherwise someone might spend time typing the same answer, which will yield the same results.